# Calling Jquery focusIn function on elements in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that contains several text boxes. I am trying to have a javascript function execute by calling the Jquery `focusIn()` function on the text box in question. The problem is these elements within the modal are not letting the Jquery function execute for some reason.

Comment: can you show the specific JS you are using and the corresponding HTML?

Comment: @Kyle 

`
<asp:Textbox runat="server" ID="txtID" CssClass="txtID">
$(".txtID").focusIn(){function() {
      //some code
}}
`

Comment: do you see an error in the console?  I'm pretty sure it's $(".txtID").focusin(){function() { // ... "focusin" all lowercase